# Can we clone a repository if we are a valid user?

Tags: git

I am new to Git, so please excuse if this is a dumb question.

In our organization we use Git as our repository and I can do `git checkin`, `checkout`, `pull`, ... from my office machines.

Our Git repository URL is something like this (but I can;t paste the original due to restrictions): `git@github.com:test/hkin.git`

My question is: Can I `clone`/`checkout`/`fetch` the above repository into my personal machine? (I have the git username and password)

Comment: What happened when you installed Git on your personal machine and tried to clone the repository using that URL?

Comment: i got  Permission denied

Comment: Then the answer, in this specific case, is simply "no" (assuming you entered the credentials correctly).

Comment: Go to your admins and politely ask them.

Comment: stop impressing people at @KCrunchhh

Answer (score 3):

Remember that Git does not do any authentication itself (through [local or git daemon protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html)).
You need a listening service (https or ssh) to authenticate, and *then* pass along your git request to git itself afterwards (along with your id), or to an [authorization layer like gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) (which, in turn, calls or does not call git, authorizing or denying your request).

So it is not so much a git problem than more of a [WAN (Wide Area Network)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) access issue.

Usually, corporation networks are closed to the outside world, and allow external connections only through [VPN (Virtual Private Network)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN), accessed first with a [SecurID tokens](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-13681566).

[image: SecurId token]

Then you enter your usual login/password in order to open a connection on (for instance) a [Citrix farm](http://www.smali.net/administrators/install-citrix-secure-gateway.html).

[image]

Then you can, if authorized, [mstsc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) ([remote desktop connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol)) to your own workstation.
From there, you have the proper environment to do your git operations.

This is only one example of external access management, but I have often seen this kind of setup in large corporations.

Comment: :) np, but the last line is not yet fine somehow. I just did not want to make yet another edit. hf!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether your personal machine is able to connect to the machine that your Git repository is hosted on. (If your office machines talk to the Git repository's machine via an internal network, your personal home computer might not be able to reach it.)